# Get list of all issues across an organisation filtered by label

Tags: github

According to [the GitHub API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues),

```
GET /orgs/:org/issues
```

returns all the issues assigned to the authenticated user across all repos in the given organization.

So for I want I've tried

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/my-org/issues?filter=all&label=my-label
```

but that returns `message: "Not Found"`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer you're looking for, but you can use the search endpoint to do the same thing:

`curl https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=org:my-org&type:issue`